# Resolucão de método

Tags: java

no exemplo abaixo

```
public static void foo(Integer i) {
    System.out.println("foo(Integer)");
}

public static void foo(short i) {
    System.out.println("foo(short)");
}

public static void foo(long i) {
    System.out.println("foo(long)");
}

public static void foo(int... i) {
    System.out.println("foo(int ...)");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    foo(10);
}
```

foo chama o método com assinatura long, porque a JVM resolve que o tipo mais próximo de int é long, o que é compreensível.

ele prefere fazer isso a chamar o método com assinatura Integer ou int... (array), que seriam perfeitamente compatíveis.

qual o motivo, em termos de design da linguagem, para que "long" seja mais adequado do que Integer ou int...? É caro para a JVM fazer este tipo de casting internamente? (seja para int[] ou Integer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De acordo com [a especificação do Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2), as regras de conversão são aplicadas de modo a não quebrar a compatibilidade com as versões antigas - que não suportavam *autoboxing* nem métodos com número variável de parâmetros. Dessa forma, é considerado:

1. Uma das [conversões de tipo aplicáveis a métodos](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3), desde que não envolvam *autoboxing*/*autounboxing* ou um número variável de argumentos;
2. Idem, mas agora permitindo também *autoboxing*/*autounboxing*;
3. Idem, mas agora permitindo também métodos com número variável de parâmetros.

Dessa forma, como durante a fase 1 foi encontrado um método aplicável (aquele com parâmetro `long`) a resolução não vai pras fases 2 e 3, de modo que as demais opções são desconsideradas. Também pelas regras acima, se não houvesse solução na fase 1 o próximo método a ser considerado seria o que recebe `Integer`, e por último o que recebe `int...`. O que recebe `short` não é válido porque implica num tipo mais restrito (*narrowing primitive conversions*) - o que não é aplicável na chamada de método.

Comment: +1 compatibilidade. ótimo ponto, obrigado